# Descargar archivo de mi servidor sin saber extensión

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Buenas, tengo una duda y es que tengo un formulario para poder subir documentos a mi servidor (no importa su extensión), por lo que los archivos almacenados allí tienen extensiones diferentes: jpge, jpg, png, pdf...etc

Lo que quiero es que reconozca la extensión automaticamente para poder descargar/visualizar sea el tipo de archivo que sea

Necesito saber por qué no me reconoce la extensión del archivo almacenado en mi servidor con el siguiente código.

```html
<?php 
        // la variable albarán normalmente es una serie de numeros. ej: 51484
        $albaran = $row['albaran']; //Me traigo el nombre del archivo
        $tipo_archivo = file_get_contents("albaranes/" . $albaran);  // albaranes/ es la carpeta
        $tipo_archivo = explode("/", $tipo_archivo);
        $tipo_archivo= '.' . $tipo_archivo[1];
        $nombre_archivo= $albaran . $tipo_archivo; 
?>

<?php if ($row['albaran'] != ""): ?>

<a href="albaranes/<?php echo $nombre_archivo; ?>">Ver albarán Nº <?php echo $nombre_archivo; ?></a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ya está actualizado

Comment: No se podría dar el caso, porque los documentos que se suben son abaranes reales con una numeración única.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, lo que buscas es sencillo, pero quizás tengamos que añadir algo de control. Vamos primero con el código:

```
$albaran = $row['albaran'];
$directorio = 'albaranes/'; 
$ruta = glob($directorio . $albaran . '.*');

if($ruta) echo '<a href="' . $ruta[0] . '">Ver albarán Nº: ' . $albaran . '</a>';
```

Con esto generamos el enlace que quieres, pero ahora bien ¿que pasa si existen dos documentos con el mismo nombre?, entiendo que eso lo tienes controlado. De ser así, con este pequeño código te servirá.

Saludos,

Comment: Funciona a la perfeccion, gracias!

Comment: Hola @Mariano, lo puse al no saber si el usuario tenía controlado el que no hubieran más ficheros con el mismo nombre, por si tenía que agregar algún condicional. En este caso, al darlo como válido entiendo que lo tendrá controlado, efectivamente podemos evitar el uso de `foreach`, edito la respuesta para reflejarlo.